# How can I create a cubic spline to connect these two line segments?

Tags: graphing-functions, cubics, spline, smooth-functions

I am trying to create an audio envelope smoothing curve to smooth a steady signal (y=1) as it goes into exponential decay (y=c^-x).

I have expressed the graphs of the two line segments I am trying to connect in terms of the variables I need here:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/85lw0cmyw7

[image: cubic spline needed]

In this case, how would I connect the two segments with a cubic spline between x=0 and x=f?

I am trying to smooth between y = 1 and y = c ^ (d - x) over this range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cubic equation will be,

$$y = Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D,$$

we need to determine the coefficients $A,B,C,$ and $D$. These will be determined by the  two functions we are trying to join together. Our cubic will have to match their values, and the values of their derivatives at the boundary points.

Here is our overall function,

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}  
1 \qquad x \leq 0 \\ 
Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D \qquad 0 < x<f\\ 
c^{-(x-d)} \qquad x \geq f
\end{cases} 
$$

First we enforce continuity.

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow f^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow f^+} f(x)$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f'(x)$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow f^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow f^+} f'(x)$$

these equations need to be solved for $A,B,C,$ and $D$.

---

It's relatively easy to show that $D=1$ and $C=0$.

We will work through the calculation to solve for $A$ and $B$.

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow f^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow f^+} f(x)$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow f^-} \Big( Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D \Big) = \lim_{x\rightarrow f^+} \Big( c^{-(x-d)} \Big)$$

$$ Af^3+Bf^2+Cf+D  =  c^{-(f-d)} $$

$$ Af^3+Bf^2+0f+1  =  c^{d-f} $$

$$ \boxed{Af^3+Bf^2 =  c^{d-f}-1} \quad \textbf{(1)}$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow f^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow f^+} f'(x)$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow f^-} \Big(3Ax^2+2Bx+C\Big) = \lim_{x\rightarrow f^+} \Big( - \ln(c) c^{-(x-d)}\Big)$$

$$ 3Af^2+2Bf+C = - \ln(c) c^{-(f-d)}$$

$$ 3Af^2+2Bf+0 = - \ln(c)c^{d-f}$$

$$ \boxed{3Af^2+2Bf = -\ln(c) c^{d-f}}\quad \textbf{(2)}$$

---

To avoid potential errors I used wxMaxima to solve the equations,

[image]

---

I then checked the results using a plotting software called gnuplot. The following is for $c=5$ and $f=0.76$.

[image]

The code to make this plot is here :

```
d=0.4
f=0.76
c=5

F(x) = c**(-(x-d))
G(x) = 1

A = - (c**d * log(c) * f - 2 * c**f + 2 * c**d)/(c**f * f**3)
B = (c**d * log(c) * f - 3 * c**f + 3 * c**d ) / (c**f * f **2 ) 

C = 0 
D = 1

P(x) = A*x**3+B*x**2+C*x+D

piecewise(x) = x < 0? G(x) : x <= f ? P(x) :  F(x) 
set xrange[0:f+1]
set yrange[0:c**(d)]

plot piecewise(x), c**(-(x-d))
```

---

Here is a link to the updated Desmos graph : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kt2xzjwbui

You should be aware that wherever I have "log(c)" in the wxMaxima or gnuplot code that this refers to the natural logarithm.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, that's very helpful to explain the concept. I tried to work through it and I seem to have met 3 of the 4 conditions. The derivative and point match at x=0, but I can only get the point to match at x=f, not the derivative. I've gone through my work a few times and used online equation solvers to help check, but I'm still not sure what I've done wrong. Any further help? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dg1eetwbzg

Comment: Hope this helps. Its entirely possible that I may have made a minor error, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. Based on that, my error was in equation (2) I had equated the derivative of the cubic with the derivative of f(f)=c^(d-f), which makes no sense. But unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work fully either. I'm not sure if it is a problem with your equation (2) perhaps as well, as it also doesn't make sense to me. You're saying the rate of change of the cubic (derivative) should equal the y value of the exponential at x=f. But I don't think that seems correct either, is it? Why would those two things be equal? Here's yours: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ctzqomlard

Comment: We are matching the slopes at the point $x=f$. The derivative (slope) of an exponential is itself, there is an extra negative sign because of the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. Yeah - right - I just looked up some more basics on derivatives and tangents - It's been 20 years since I learned this stuff in high school (and I haven't touched it since until now)! In principle it makes sense then. But so why isn't it working?

Comment: I am not sure why it isn't working. I messed with your Desmos file for quite a while and had limited success. I have attached a plot I made using the software called gnuplot.

Comment: Okay, no worries Spencer! If the math is good then that is all that matters! I will be doing this in C++, where it should run fine if the math is correct. I guess desmos is just glitchy. I have encountered other glitchy behaviors on there before. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries! If it works out please remember to come back and accept the answer :). And if not then let me know and I will try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Well I won't actually be able to see the curve since it will be processing audio (unless I build an extra visualizer, which I won't), so I will take your word for it that it is working based on your own plot and Desmos being screwy sometimes. Answer accepted. :)

Comment: Oh I actually did find an error, in my vision. I read your "c" as an "e" as in eulers number. If the base of the exponent isn't "e" then there are some extra factors that need to go in. I will fix this now.

Comment: Oh yes definitely. That would explain it. It's "c" as in an arbitrary constant for the exponential decay. I was wondering why you had put "e" and figured you were just changing the name of the variable so it wouldn't clash with "C" from the cubic... Thanks for the attention.

Comment: No worries, I will take some time to check my solution for errors. I will let you know when I am finsihed.

Comment: Here is the updated Desmos graph : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kt2xzjwbui

Comment: Thanks again man. Looks beautiful. Looks like I actually had the right idea the first time with my equation (2). I just screwed up the math in solving the equations for A and B. I appreciate the knowledge and explanations.